# Signal processing and modulation in Simulink

Tags: matlab, signal-processing, simulink

I want to add input to my Simulink model from PC / Laptop keyboard. I found a few similar s-functions in which this opportunity is implemented but the problem is that it only shows a discrete "peak" of a signal which only tells that a key was pressed but I need to know for how long a key was pressed.
So I came up with idea that I can can use ASK demodulation but apparently I was wrong.

To sum up:

1. I have an ASCII code of a key in a signal (amplitude)
2. I have a peak which says that a key was pressed.
   How can I implement input from keyboard with determining if the key is still pressed or not?

p.s. I was doing it in Simulink but it doesn't really matter i suppose. I need to find an idea how to do it.

Comment: Operating systems tend to have key up and jey down events. Look into how matlab might get those.